# Additions of tabbar and navigation bar controllers

Tags: iphone

Hii...

I have added the tabbar and navigation bar controller by using following code. But only on the first tab I have added table view and buttons but it is also displaying on others tab views. What is the problem with this code I am not able to come to know. please help me If anyone know.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //UITabBarController *tab =[[UITabBarController alloc]init];

    vc1 = [[viewcontroller alloc] init];
     nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc1];
    //vc1.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab.png"];
    vc2 = [[viewcontroller1 alloc] init];
    nc1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc2];

    vc3 = [[viewcontroller alloc] init];
    nc2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc3];

    vc4 = [[viewcontroller alloc] init];
    nc3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc4];

    vc5 = [[viewcontroller alloc] init];
    nc4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc5];

    NSArray *navControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nc, nc1, nc2, nc3, nc4, nil];
    [nc release]; 
    [nc1 release];
    [nc2 release];
    [nc3 release];
    [nc4 release];

    tab = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [tab setViewControllers:navControllers];

    [window addSubview:[tab view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    //return YES;

   // [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Thanks alot.

Comment: where you added tableView in tab one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allocating the same `viewcontroller` controller for each button except the second one, that is bound to a `viewcontroller1` instance. Maybe this could be the problem.

If you are adding the table view and buttons to the `viewcontroller` instances, maybe in the `viewDidLoad` method, this could be the cause.

Comment: Yup, You are right. I was adding same view controller by mistake. Thanks alot.